# How can I re-mount rootfs in WSL2 ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've accidently umounted /dev/sdd which was rootfs ext4 of ubuntu18.04.
I thought it was usb filesystem.
As soon as I umounted it, bash couldn't find any command like ls, cd or something.

So I exited the terminal. After that, I can't get inside again.
What I can do ? Any Suggestion?

Comment: If you have git bash you can call the mount cmd from there, but I am not sure if wsl will recognize a mount from mingw. They are both "linux env in windows" implementations, but I am not sure if mounting has a universal method, or if it is implementation specific. It is at least worth a try. If it works, let me know so I can get the rep.

Comment: This might help : https://www.xda-developers.com/wsl-2-windows-10-supports-mounting-linux-filesystems-ext4/

Comment: Ouch - What a pickle.  I have to say that I'm not sure how you accomplished that.  WSL won't let me unmount `/dev/sdc`, which is my `/` (tested on a cloned (exported/imported) instance).  It doesn't return any error; just silently exits, with the device/fs still mounted.  Is there any more detail you can remember that could be added to the question on exactly how you unmounted?  Also, what message does it give when you attempt to relaunch it?  Try from PowerShell or cmd with `wsl` or `wsl -d <distroname>` to make sure you see any errors.

Comment: Also a heads-up that this question is probably more appropriate to superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com -- Stack Overflow questions should be programming related.